# Permission dialog not showing 6.0

Tags: android, permissions, dialog, alarmmanager

I want to get `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` permissions to toggle a value there. After take a look at the documentation I got this code, however it's not showing the dialog at all.

On permission granted I call an AlarmManager to start a BroadcastReceiver, I do it on the startAlarm method. However I think it doesn't have nothing to do with my problem.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SeePermissions();


}

public void SeePermissions(){
    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS)) {

        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_SETTINGS);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_SETTINGS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Intent alarmIntent=new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                enableNightMode = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 123, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                startAlarm();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: replace ContextCompat to ActivityCompact

Comment: Does the application achieve 'requestPermissions'?

Comment: @VishalPatoliya It doesn't work either, I guess you refer the first if at the top of the method, right?

Comment: try manually off - on -off permission from settings and once you have done check in your application to dialog is disaply or not ?

Comment: @VishalPatoliya "there is no permission request" on Applications>My App> Permissions

Comment: so you have not need to write this code

Comment: you declared in Manifeast 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
??

Comment: Yes @VishalPatoliya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122273/discussion-between-vishal-patoliya-and-user1423168).